# jquery Hide show multiple divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm looking for a smarter way to hide and show multiple elements. 
The solution I have now is to create a separate script for every element I want to show, with a click on a button.

```
 <a class="pure-button pure-button-primary" type='button' id='hideshow1'     
 value='hide/show' >Show it1 !</a>
<div id='content1' style="display:none">
 lorem ipsum
</div>

<a class="pure-button pure-button-primary" type='button' id='hideshow2'     
value='hide/show' >Show 2 </a>  
<div id='content2' style="display:none">
  lorem ipsum
</div>
```

This is the script part:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('#hideshow1').on('click', function(event) {        
             jQuery('#content1').toggle('hide');
        });
    });
</script>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('#hideshow2').on('click', function(event) {        
             jQuery('#content2').toggle('hide');
        });
    });
</script>
```

This way works perfect, however I think there must be a smarter way. Anyone can give me a clue how to make it smarter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you dont have to write JS code for each element. Either you can speicify the same class `class="hide"` on all `a` tag and `data-content=""` to toggle `hide/show` (as Mostafa said). But if you want to do it by `ids`. then you can follow this code.

**https://jsfiddle.net/unnxnz71/**

**HTML**

```
      <a class="pure-button pure-button-primary" type='button' id='hideshow1' value='hide/show' data-value="content1">Show it1 !</a>
      <div id='content1' style="display:none">
        lorem ipsum
      </div>

      <a class="pure-button pure-button-primary" type='button' id='hideshow2' value='hide/show' data-value="content2">Show 2 </a>
      <div id='content2' style="display:none">
        lorem ipsum
      </div>
```

**JS**

```
    $('[id^="hideshow"]').on('click', function(event) {
      var dataValue = $(this).attr('data-value');
      dataValue = $('#'+dataValue);
      $(dataValue).toggle('hide');
    });
```

Comment: I've tried this suggestion and it works great for me. Thank you for showing this to me

Answer (score 1):

try this: add "data-content"

```
<a class="hide pure-button pure-button-primary" type='button'     
 value='hide/show' data-content="1">Show it1 !</a>
<div id='content1' style="display:none">
 lorem ipsum
</div>

<a class="pure-button pure-button-primary" type='button'     
value='hide/show' data-content="2">Show 2 </a>  
<div id='content2' style="display:none">
  lorem ipsum
</div>
```

script :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('.hide').on('click', function(event) {        
             jQuery('#content'+$(this).data("content")).toggle('hide');
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree, data attributes would work really well in this situation.

```
$(() => {

   const toggle = e => { 
      const content = '#content' + $(e.target).data('content');
      $(content).toggle('hide');
   };

   $('.pure-button').on('click', toggle);

});
```